# Why $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not definable in $(\mathbb Z, +, 0)$?

Tags: model-theory, quotient-group

Marker states in his textbook:

> It is possible that $G/H$ does not
>   correspond to a definable group in our structure.

Our instructor gave $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ as an example. But definability, again by Marker, is

> We say that $X \subseteq M^n$ is definable if and only if there is an L-formula $\phi(v_1,... , v_n, w_1, ..., w_m)$ and $b\in M^m$ such that $X = \{a ∈ M^n : M |= φ(a, b)\}$.

So, why can't we choose arbitrary elements $u,v\in\mathbb  Z$ to represent $0,1 \in\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and use them as $b$ in the definition above?

Addition in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, viewed as a relation, is defined for the following triples: $(0,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,0)$. Let's build a formula $\phi(x,y,s, u,v): (x=u \land y=u \land s=u) \lor (...)\lor (...)\lor (...)$. Resulting relation will be a subset of $\mathbb Z^3$ and will define addition from $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. More precisely, a *definable group* in a structure $M$ is given by:

- A definable set $X\subseteq M^n$ for some $n$.
- A definable function $\cdot\colon X^2\to X$.
- A definable element $e\in X$.
- A definable function $^{-1}\colon X\to X$.
- Such that the group axioms are satisfied.

Of course, specifying $e$ and $^{-1}$ are optional, since if $X$ is actually a definable group, then they can be defined from $\cdot$. In all of the above, definable usually means definable with parameters.

A consequence of this definition is that *any* finite group is definable in *any* infinite structure $M$. Just pick elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in M$, let $X$ be defined by $\bigvee_{i=1}^n (x = a_n)$, and define $\cdot$ by explicitly writing out the multiplication table of the group, as you did in your example.

It's possible that your instructor was thinking about the concept of *definable subgroup*. When your structure $(M,\cdot)$ is itself a group (possibly with additional extra structure), then a definable subgroup is a definable set $X\subseteq M$ such that $(X,\cdot)$ is a subgroup of $(M,\cdot)$. Note that the group operation here is the same, you don't get to define it in some other way. Then indeed $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not (isomorphic to) a definable subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. But this is somewhat trivial, because definability isn't relevant here: $\mathbb{Z}$ has no subgroup, definable or otherwise, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. Then, could you please provide an example of $H \leq G$, such that $G$ and $H$ are definable (in some structure), and $G/H$ is not?

Comment: @fresheed I was worried you might ask me that! I don't know any explicit example. The trouble is that you're asking for $H$ which is interpretable but not definable in $G$. It's tricky to prove that a one structure is not definable in another, and most of the tricks for doing this also show that the structure is not interpretable, so we can't use them here.